# Getting error of Null type with getelementbyid in html

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am Struck at simple code , getelementbyid.innerHtml in html page. Please help me.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Dom examples</title>
  <script>
   var code = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;
   code = code + " !!";
   console.log(code);
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h4> DOM practise page </h4>
  <p id="one"> This page is for practise of DOM model in JS</p>
  <p id="two"> Thank You </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because element with id=one not loaded yet

Comment: Have you tried `.innerText` instead of `.innerHTML`?

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is called before your browser render your HTML page. So when your browser call `getElementById` the ID isn't defined.

Just move your javascript at the end of your file

Comment: It would be enough to move the script tag after html tags.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the script below... the causing is beacause the id isnt render yet.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Dom examples</title>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <h4> DOM practise page </h4>
  <p id="one"> This page is for practise of DOM model in JS</p>
  <p id="two"> Thank You </p>
 </body>
    <script>
   var code = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;
   code = code + " !!";
   console.log(code);
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I am a new beginner to JS and Html. your suggestion helped me !! Thank you so much !! It worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

Utilize `onload` property of `window` to call a function when `window` has loaded

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Dom examples</title>
  <script>
    onload = function() {
      var code = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;
      code = code + " !!";
      console.log(code);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h4> DOM practise page </h4>
  <p id="one"> This page is for practise of DOM model in JS</p>
  <p id="two"> Thank You </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put the script part before close body and it will work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Dom examples</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4> DOM practise page </h4>
        <p id="one"> This page is for practise of DOM model in JS</p>
        <p id="two"> Thank You </p>

        <script>
            var code = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;
            code = code + " !!";
            console.log(code);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers parses html page from top to down. So, if you put your `script` in the `head`, it will get rendered first and then your `body`. So your `script` is searching for an id which is yet not rendered to the DOM.

By placing `script` at the bottom, it solves your problem.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Dom examples</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h4> DOM practise page </h4>
  <p id="one"> This page is for practise of DOM model in JS</p>
  <p id="two"> Thank You </p>
    <script>
   var code = document.getElementById("one");
   code = code.innerHTML + " !!";
   console.log(code);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine just use script tag in end. For more clearity check.
https://jsfiddle.net/djmayank/Lzewxgyw/

HTML

```
<head>
        <title>Dom examples</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h4> DOM practise page </h4>
        <p id="one"> This page is for practise of DOM model in JS</p>
        <p id="two"> Thank You </p>
    </body>
```

JS

```
var code = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;
        code = code + " !!";
        console.log(code);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `script` is loaded before your element with the id of one is loaded, therefore one does not exist yet. You have the following options:

1. You put the script after the tag you need:

   `<!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <title>Dom examples</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <h4> DOM practise page </h4>
           <p id="one"> This page is for practise of DOM model in JS</p>
           <p id="two"> Thank You </p>
           <script>
               var code = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;
               code = code + " !!";
               console.log(code);
           </script>
       </body>
   </html>`
2. Make a `function` and use the `onload` attribute, which is preferable, as the code will be reusable for other features:

   `<!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <title>Dom examples</title>
           <script>
               function myFunction() {
                   var code = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;
                   code = code + " !!";
                   console.log(code);
               }
           </script>
       </head>
       <body>
           <h4> DOM practise page </h4>
           <p id="one" onload="myFunction()"> This page is for practise of DOM model in JS</p>
           <p id="two"> Thank You </p>
       </body>
   </html>`